# what is the equivalent in python of the expression below?

Tags: python

What is the equivalent in python of the expression below?

```
EE_DOUBLE const yplus = ( y < 1.0 ) ? y*u_tau/nu_inf : (2.0-y)*u_tau/nu_inf
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Many thanks A

Comment: What is the confusion? Do you know what ternary operator is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: I am afraid that I don't know Eugene.

Comment: So you have an excellent opportunity to learn about it! You have the keyword, you know what to do.

Comment: @EugeneSh. didn't know the term either, nice link !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about C syntax anymore, but i guess it'll look like this :

```
yplus =  y*u_tau/nu_inf if ( y < 1.0 ) else (2.0-y)*u_tau/nu_inf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yplus = ((2.0-y)*u_tau/nu_inf, y*u_tau/nu_inf)[y < 1.0]
```

other way

```
yplus = (y < 1.0) and (y*u_tau/nu_inf) or ((2.0-y)*u_tau/nu_inf)
```

other way

```
yplus = {True: y*u_tau/nu_inf, False: (2.0-y)*u_tau/nu_inf} [y < 1.0]
```

other way marked already by others

```
yplus = (y*u_tau)/nu_inf if y < 1.0 else (2.0-y)*u_tau/nu_inf
```

other way

```
if (y < 1.0):
  yplus = (y*u_tau)/nu_inf
else:
  yplus = (2.0-y)*u_tau/nu_inf
```

Comment: I guess the expressions should be swapped. But nice idea. Is it idiomatic?

Comment: @EugeneSh.  the idea comes from lisp systems, where each operator can treat a value in different ways, for example here what is supposed to be a boolean is treated by []-ref operator as integer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's ternary operator added since 2.5

```
yplus = (y*u_tau)/nu_inf if y < 1.0 else (2.0-y)*u_tau/nu_inf
```